# What are the events that EVMd process in Oracle RAC distributes across cluster?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, rac

I am new to Oracle RAC. I was studying about Oracle RAC background processes, in which I came across EVMd process which distributes the event message across other nodes in the cluster.

Could you please make me understand, what are these event message? I worked on it but didn't get proper answer.

Thanks
Prabhakar

Answer (score 1):

The Cluster Ready Services (CRS) process is the primary program for managing high availability operations(start, stop, monitor, and fail over) in a cluster.

The `crsd` process generates events when the status of a resource changes and `EVMd` publishes these events.

For example, if one of the cluster node goes down then the VIP running  should fail over to another node. 
In this case `crsd` does the work of fail over and that changes the status of the resource-which is VIP in our example.

`EVMd` process distributes such events to all of the cluster members so that they are aware of the cluster changes.